# WPF using style that contains another style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a progress bar style that is re-usable.

So the idea here is very simple. I have a style already with target type ProgressBar, and it's just a spinny circle that fills as it goes from 0-100%. However, in order to make it re-usable and modular, I do not want to hard-code the text that goes along with it - it should be optional.

So I want to create another style that DOES include text "Downloading... X/Y MB". For this I take Value for X, Maximum for Y, and Tag for the unit. I want to include the same spinny circle thingy for the graphical part on the left. How can I do this? With BasedOn property, I think you can only set something already there to be different. What if I want to add additional elements (like textblocks in this case)?

Comment: simple answer: key is `BasedOn` property

Answer (score 0):

If only text value differentiates then within style you can bind propertie's value to parent's property like Tag where at every single either style or element you adjust it to specific requirement.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FirstButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SecondButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource FirstButtonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource FirstButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource SecondButtonStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The outcome is 1 and 2. 
 If your intent is to inject some UI element within style then there is no such an option, alas. Style needs to be rewritten once again.

Comment: I see. What I intend is to be able to add whatever on any side of it, basically have another control that can use all the animations I've done for this element. It would be part of another control.

Comment: Can I inject this animated progress circle into another control with a contentcontrol?

Comment: I do not have insight whay you mean. Could you elaborate?